# Custom Field of plugin does not update the value when assigned in Joomla Article

Tags: php, xml, plugins, joomla, joomla3.0

Joomla 3.4 Stable Version, Content Plugin

Simply explain the problem > [click here](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=706&t=896220)

Picture of custom field which assigned '5555' : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qlsS.png

Expected Output: 
5555

Real Output :
defaultvalue

Print Output Code

```
$plugin = JPluginHelper::getPlugin('content', 'signal');

$params = new JRegistry($plugin->params);

echo $params->get('custom_1','default_value');
```

XML Code

```
<field name="custom_1"
       type="text"
       label="Custom Field 1"
       />
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: let us know what is the content of $plugin variable.

Comment: Please supply all the information.  Where does 5555 come from ?  It's no where in the code

Comment: @RohitGupta Most likely the 5555 value is written in the Joomla backend in the plugin's "settings / parameters"

Comment: Second time I use SO sorry for any mistake, and thank a lot for help me.

Comment: @AphikritGerbertSaravasri, Please do not use links or answers to supply more information.  Just edit the post and type in more information so that others can help you.

Answer (score 0):

From the image it seems that the parameter you try to acess is not in the plugin ,but it is in the article (new field created by plugin) so try to use this code

```
$params= json_decode($this->item->attribs);
echo $params->custom_1;
```

Comment: It return

Undefined property: plgContentSignal::$item

Trying to get property of non-object in (file location)

Comment: You understand correctly but the code not work at this time. Thank for help.

Comment: forgot to tell that the $this->item is the article object , so if it is different in your case change it. Also it would be helpfull if you could tell where you try to use it, e.g template overwrite.

Comment: I try to print the value of a field in plugin.php file. in onContentPrepareForm method. I expected the assigned value, but it always return default value regardless of value I assigned.

Comment: then you should be able to find your attributes in the `$data` variable of the onContentPrepareForm

Comment: try to access it through $data->attribs->custom_1

Comment: What should I assign to $data variable

Comment: the function onContentPrepareData must have 2 parameters (context and data) , in the second parameter you should see your custom field

Comment: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in (file location).
When I add  $data->attribs->custom_1; to the file

Comment: as you can see inside the $data variable there is custom_1 field. Sorry my mistake probably was that you should access the variable like this `$data->attribs['custom_1']`